# How to publish my symfony2 bundles?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I am trying to find a documentation or a tutorial about creating and publishing symfony2 bundles for other developer use.

I tried to look at some source code for some public bundles but it seems it needs more in dept   understanding.

Is there any official documentation about this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find most of the recommendations from the official symfony documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

I also encourage you to read this slides from the famous @stof70 and @lsmith, that exposes the most recent best practices about bundles (composer, travis, knpbundles, etc) : http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/slides/there_is_a_bundle_for_that.html#1

Answer (score 2):

There is no official documentation on this topic. But from my point of view I can tell you, that most important things for you bundle are:

- Uniqueness
- **README**
- Tests
- Avoiding dependencies

Good practice also is to tag stable releases.

By the way, at [KnpBundles](http://knpbundles.com/) you can see the number left to the bundle name. It represents respectability of bundle within community. You can check most respectable and the looser ones, compare and analyze them to define points, that make bundles successful.